# React Native, UI Kitten Input custom style on default and onFocus states

Tags: react-native-ui-kitten

I need some help about creating a custom input style on default and onFocus states.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  Input,
  Layout,
} from '@ui-kitten/components';

export const CustomInputExample = () => {
  const [ focusStatus, setFocusStatus ] = useState(false)

  const onMouseEnter = () => {
     setFocusStatus(true)
  }

  const onMouseLeave = () => {
     setFocusStatus(false)
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Input
        style={focusStatus ? styles.customStyle : styles.basicStyle}
        status={focusStatus ? 'success' : 'basic'}
        placeholder='Success'
        onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
      />
    </Layout>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  basicStyle: {
    borderColor: grey,
  },
  customStyle: {
    borderColor: '#3CB46E'
  },
});
```

But, none of the methods are working in my case. I've tried other InputProps like focus, onTextFieldFocus, onTextFieldBlur...May be I do not know how to use them.

Also this is the error from ts =>

> Property 'onMouseEnter' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'.ts(2322)

Any help can be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

`onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` will not work unless you build a custom component and then only if you use [TouchableWeb](https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/blob/master/src/components/devsupport/components/touchableWeb.component.tsx). Additionally it will only work on web (No hover events on phone or tablet).

Of course this will require writing your own mapping following UI-Kitten's [Create a Custom Component Mapping](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/design-system/custom-component-mapping#create-a-custom-component-mapping) directions

Answer (score 0):

At last, I've found the solution. I'am writing to help others who uses react-native-ui-kitten.

InputComponent implements WebEventResponderCallbacks interface so =>

```
export interface WebEventResponderCallbacks {
    onMouseEnter?: () => void;
    onMouseLeave?: () => void;
    onFocus?: () => void;
    onBlur?: () => void;
}
```

I don't know the reason why onMouseEnter, onMouseLeave or any other methods of InputComponent have no use but onFocus and onBlur are working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement these interfaces in case you follow [Branding](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/guides/branding#branding) guide. You can change primary colors everywhere so your app will follow a single source of truth about styling.